# RESTful Design for non CRUD APIs

Tags: c#, rest

I have been trying to find a tutorial or site that explains the best practice(s) for designing an api that doesn't just represent resources in a typical Create-Read-Update-Delete.

Let's say I wanted to represent typical APIs found in base class libraries (some which represent Singleton patterns/Factory patterns etc) in a RESTful fashion, the majority of tutorial and information I can find about simple POST, PUT, GET, DELETE methods to represent Create, Read, Update do not suffice.

Are there a standard set of guidelines for 'RESTifying' more complex APIs and/or standard design patterns in a RESTful fashion?

As an example, the best approach for providing MOVE and COPY operations to an instance of a file is not clear to me, and there are many (so!) many ways in which this could be implemented;

```
POST http://www.api.com/api/file/<fileidentifier>/COPYTO/<newfileidentifier>
```

or

```
POST http://www.api.com/api/file?directory=<dir>&filename=<filename>
BODY { operation: "copy", newDirectory: "<$newdir>", newFilename: "<$newfilename>"
```

etc, etc

What design guidelines should I adhere to?

Comment: Well, a file seems to be a resource in your case. That file has some attributes: a name and a location. When you "move" your resource, you are updating its location, so I would use a PUT on that resource (identified by "fileidentifier") and pass the new location in the request body.

Comment: Perhaps not the best example as I mixed the move and copy operations. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Copying a resource is creating a new resource based on an existing one. So I would use a POST /files?source=/files/<fileidentifier> (note that I used a plural form for the file resource. Seems to be a collection, according to your context)

Comment: Thanks David - agree completely with the use of the plural. The choice of example may be getting in the way of the question here, but let's stick with it for now. Of course, in the copy example, the onus could be put on the client to do a 'get' and then to create a new instance using a POST RESTful query. If the intention is for this to be done using a server-side function however (i.e. why download a large file to the client, only to upload it again), how would you structure the API?

Comment: Mmmh? If you do a copy of an existing resource, your resource is already on the server side, isn't it? So the function associated to your POST is doing everything on the server side. It's just triggering the copy, creating a new identifier for it and returning it as the result of the copy operation.

Comment: I am possibly missing the obvious then! Could you possibly provide an example of how the POST request would be structured, and how you would differentiate between a copy and a 'new' file?

Answer (score 0):

i will prefer you to add up Odata v4  into this and then create services, as i am working on the same scenario from past 8 months.
**benefits**
1. no need to make many of search query functions.
2. there is Odata client available which generates client code based on Metadata as Wcf does.
so which is also a big advantage.
3. instead of using put post get basic name conventions of API use your function names which are more descriptive to what the function is actually doing.

Comment: So your advice is "don't use REST"?

Comment: you will be using Rest, but not to use all basic methods. instead of using other method names with http attributes which describes the method type